# Using $_Get with Radio Buttons and Drop Down list

Tags: php, html

I have sucessfully sent my data to my page in the form of the url :

```
http://localhost:8101/Tutorials/sandbox/myfiles/make_a_booking.php?period=2&date=04/29/2014&room=028
```

But I am struggling to place the data into the form. But how would I place the period=2 into the radio buttons and the room=028 into the select drop down?

```
<form class="submit_date" method="post" action="insert.php" id="submit_date" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirm your booking?');">           
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" required value="<?php echo $_GET['date'];?>"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="1" required/>1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="2" required/>2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="3" required/>3<br>    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="4" required/>4<br>    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="5" required/>5<br>
    <select class="dropdown" id="bookroom" name="bookroom" required;>
    <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
    <?php
    for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($rooms_array); $x++)
     {           
     echo "<option value='$rooms_array[$x]'>".$rooms_array[$x]."</option>";
     }
     ?> 
    </select>
    <input  class="submit_btn" value="Submit" type="submit" name="Submit";/>      
  </form>
```

I've tried placing the room=028 into option via $_GET but it hasnt worked and the radio buttons I wouldnt know where to begin.

Comment: you check the value of each button against the variable if they match you output the html to mark the input checked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use php for that:

```
<?php 
$selectedPerion = $_GET['period'];

for($x = 1; $x < 6; $x++):  // short notation to separate php and html better?>

<input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="<?php echo $x ?>" required 
<?php echo ($selectedPerion == $x ? 'checked' : ''); //so called 'ternary operator' ?>/>
<?php echo $x ?>
<br>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Or you can use jQuery to set the 'checked' property or simulate click on the proper button, but that's another story.

it is similar for the select dropdown, you have to add the 'selected' property to proper "" tag, or set the value for bookroom field with jQuery.

Comment: sidenote: be aware that some browsers ignore `required` attribute so don't forget to check your `input` on submit with `isset()` or to validate entire form using JavaScript before submit.